# How to extract text from HTML with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

website = 'https://www.klavkarr.com/data-trouble-code-obd2.php?dtc=p0000-p0299#dtc'
result = requests.get(website)
content = result.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

box = soup.find('div', class_='main_article-blog')

title = box.find('table')

headers = [header for header in title.find_all('th')]
results = [{headers[i]: cell for i, cell in enumerate(row.find_all('td'))}
       for row in title.find_all('tr')]
```

Hi everyone, I'm trying to scrape with python and Beautifulsoup some codes and make a dictionary with them, but in the output I see also the html codes like

```
"[{}, {<th>Code</th>: <td>P0000</td>, <th>Description </th>: ecc"
```

How can I get only the text of this?

Comment: get_text() method. headers[i].get_text(strip=True): cell.get_text(strip=True)

Answer (score 1):

Simply call [`.text` or better `.get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) on your elements in list comprehension to extract only the strings:

```
[
    {
        headers[i].get_text(): cell.get_text() 
        for i, cell in enumerate(row.find_all('td'))
    }
    for row in title.find_all('tr')
]
```